# How to grab data from VBA Access form and use that data in Outlook userform?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Example:

I have outlook VBAproject with userform which contains field "Name". And on button press i want to grab data from opened Access file (123.accdb), from ABC_FORM and "FName" field and put it to outlook userform to field "Name". Do you have any suggestions how i can establish connection between to different/separate forms?

Comment: Temporarily save the value in Excel in some cell (maybe even on a hidden temp sheet) or in a temporary table in Access. Alternatively, you can also write the data (you wish to pass on) in a temporary (maybe even hidden) text file which gets deleted afterwards. If you want to directly access userforms at runtime then you'd have to make the forms `vbModeless`. But I am not sure if (even then) you can directly access them from one application through another (at runtime).

Comment: You could use properties in the userform or look at API programming maybe

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you mean by a userform or form, as they are very different things.  A UserForm is a form you can design in the Outlook VBA Editor and is generally not accessible from external scripting.  It's possible you can access it by creating a public macro/procedure, but that's not really a supported usage.

If you mean a custom Outlook Form - as in a customized email, task, contact or appointment message - then you should already have your custom fields defined in that form definition when you publish it to the Personal Forms Library (or folder or organizational libraries).  Form Regions are also a different kind of custom form and can display custom properties, but I don't think you are working with these kinds of forms.

You can also add ad-hoc custom properties to any Outlook item, or work with them in the same way whether they are in a custom form or not.  See this article for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff869735.aspx